# Why 'src' appears in address bar in Angular App?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api, angular-ui-router

I am learning Angular 4 with ASP.NET Web API Template in Backend. I added routing in my app. It works fine but there is redundant folder name appears in Address Bar [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylGSE.png). How can I remove this?

My Project Structure is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iha1I.png).

Comment: Because you've set the root of your site to be one folder higher than it should be.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @erik-funkenbusch. But how can I solve this? My application root page is Views/Home/Index.

Comment: delete the `index.html` in the src folder

Comment: Its not working. @AmayaSan

Comment: @Md.RasedurRahmanRoxy - No, your homepage is NOT Views/Home/Index.  That's your view, not your homepage.  The homepage is based on the routes setup and which controller is called.  Views have nothing to do with it. - The homepage root is set on the webserver.  It should point to your source directory as the site root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, none of the answer is acceptable, but everyone's answer and comments helped me a lot. Thanks guys.

Following @kamrul-hasan-shahed I changed my `<base href="/src/">` to `<base href="/">`, but no luck. Then I study @erik-funkenbusch 's comment and cut all my files & folders of /src folder and paste all in root directory. Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

In index.html set

```
<base href="/">
```

Hope this will solve your problem.